# refactor this javascript code

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have two click-events, that are nearly similar, but not quite. I am wondering how to refactor them best:

```
  $('.remove_fields.dynamic').live('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var after_removal_trigger_node = $this.closest(".nested-fields").parent();
    trigger_removal_callback($this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.closest(".nested-fields").remove();
    trigger_after_removal_callback(after_removal_trigger_node);
  });

  $('.remove_fields.existing').live('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var after_removal_trigger_node = $this.closest(".nested-fields").parent();
    trigger_removal_callback($this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $this.closest(".nested-fields").hide();
    trigger_after_removal_callback(after_removal_trigger_node);
  });
```

As you can tell there is a fair bit of overlap. I am wondering what the best/nicest way would be to refactor this code.

Comment: Step 1: Don't use `.live()`. It's been deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a class check in the `.remove_fields` click function.

```
$('.remove_fields').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var after_removal_trigger_node = $this.closest(".nested-fields").parent();
    trigger_removal_callback($this);
    e.preventDefault();
    if($this.hasClass("dynamic") {
        $this.closest(".nested-fields").remove();
    } else if($this.hasClass("existing")) {
        $this.prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
        $this.closest(".nested-fields").hide();
    }
    trigger_after_removal_callback(after_removal_trigger_node);
});
```

Comment: `trigger_after_removal_callback` is common in both cases, you can factor it to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Combine the selectors into `$('.remove_fields.dynamic, .remove_fields.existing')`.

Then, test if `$this` has class `existing`. If so, run `$this.prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");`.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

taking cleaning a bit more:

```
$('.remove_fields').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $nestedFields = $this.closest(".nested-fields");

    trigger_removal_callback($this);

    if($this.hasClass("dynamic") {
        $nestedFields.remove();
    } else if($this.hasClass("existing")) {
        $this.prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
        $nestedFields.hide();
    }

    trigger_after_removal_callback($nestedFields.parent());

});
```